# solidity-coverage giving wrong report

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing, coverage, solidity-coverage

The first time I ran `npx hardhat coverage` it hadn't removed the files that should be ignored and I got this result, which is correct.

[image]

But after I added this to `.solcover.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  skipFiles: ['ignore', "mock"]
};
```

I got this result, which doesn't make any sense, since all the tests passed.

[image]

What can this be?

Comment: Hi, I'm having your same problem. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to run : `npx hardhat clean` before running coverage.